# How can I integrate Solr5.1.0 with Nutch1.10

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, nutch, solr-schema

I replaced the Solr `schema.xml` with nutch `schema.xml`.  But when I run Solr again，Solr log prints this error:

> ERROR - 2015-06-09 09:54:30.279; [   ]
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer; Error creating core [mycore]:
>   Could not load conf for core mycore: Unknown fieldType 'int' specified
>   on field cityConfidence. Schema file is
>   /opt/solr-5.1.0/server/solr/mycore/conf/schema.xml
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core
>   mycore: Unknown fieldType 'int' specified on field cityConfidence.
>   Schema file is /opt/solr-5.1.0/server/solr/mycore/conf/schema.xml

Comment: Do not copy and replace schema.xml file. Just try to copy your required fields from nutch one to the solr one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Nutch `schema.xml` file doesn't contains the field type `int` used by `cityConfidence` field. To solve this problem just include the followed line in your `schema.xml` file:

```
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

Make sure all field types used by your fields are declared in your `schema.xml` file.

Comment: yes,I add this to my schema.xml,but there are other error  “ Unknown fieldType 'tdouble' specified on field cityConfidence.” I don't know whether I use the wrong schema.xml

Comment: It's the same issue. You just need to add the following line to your `schema.xml` file: `<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>`

Answer (score 0):

try **schema-solr4.xml** instead of schema.xml